# On initial load page transition snaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So when the page first loads and the user enters input the progress bar "snaps" to the first location, rather ease in like the others. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my css

```
 .top {
background: #009dff;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1031;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
transition:all 1s;
height:54px;
}
```

And [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/U8F2p/2/) a fiddle. Press run then enter an input.Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have not given it a default width, and therefore it is defaulting to `auto`. `auto` is not a value that can be animated, therefore it snaps the first time you give it value.

Try adding `width: 0` to your CSS.